# How to compare user input to string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a code which takes an input from a user. If the user says yes or yea, then the code will print 'thank you'. But if the user inputs anything else, i.e. 'no', then the code outputs something else.

```
userinput = input('Have you entered your chosen sentences into UserSentences?:  ')
userinput = str(input)
userinput.lower()
if userinput is('yes') or ('yea'):
    print ('Thank you')
else:
    print('please enter sentences into UserSentences')
```

But when I input, 'no' the code still returns 'thank you'

Comment: I have fixed it, i changed the ('yes') or ('yea'), to ('yes' or 'yea')

Comment: if userinput in ('yes', 'yea'):

Comment: `or ('yea')` will always evaluate to `True`

Comment: If you're using python 3 you don't need to use `str` to your `input` becaus it'll be string by default. Also your line with `userinput.lower()` doing nothing because it's not inplace operation.

Comment: doesnt matter, only outputs, prints 'please enter sentences into UserSentences' no matter the input

Comment: `if userinput == 'yes' or userinput == 'yea':` or `if userinput in ('yes', 'yea'):`

Comment: userinput = raw_input('Have you entered your chosen sentences into UserSentences?:  ')
userinput.lower()
if userinput in ['yes','yea']:
    print ('Thank you')
else:
    print('please enter sentences into UserSentences')